# Vb.NET Disabling timer when window loses focus

Tags: vb.net, timer, window, focus

I'm developing a quiz software in vb. Net that has two separate windows after login. I've added timers to each of the windows. But the issue is how do I disable the timer count of one window when the mouse focus is on the other window??

Comment: Use the form's Deactivate event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans suggested, use the form [Deactivate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) event.

```
Private Sub Form1_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Deactivate
    ' deactivate this forms timer
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Hans and Saragis, I finally implemented it. Thank a lot Saragis